# Resizing event not firing when page is loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
    if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 500) {
        // My Code.
    }
}, false);
```

"My Code" takes effect **only** if I change the clientWidth(resize browser window, for example) **after** the page is loaded, even if the clientWidth condition is true from beginning.

My goal is to fire "My Code" if the clientWidth condition is true, both: 1) if clientWidth changed after the loading(browser resize) 2) When the page is loading

Comment: you could use `$(window).width()` to make it working.

Comment: Could you please provide the example?

Comment: Just refactor the code you need to run in those two cases into a single function and call that function on `$(document).ready` and `$(window).resize`

Comment: resize fires only on a resize .. you will have to trigger the event on page load to have it fire initially

Comment: It is not only the resize, but the condition. I removed the eventListener in order to check this and this is still not fired from the beginning. Is this only happens to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this :

```
function myFunction() {
    if ($(window).width() < 500) {
        alert('<500')
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    myFunction();
});

$(window).resize(function(e) {
   myFunction();
});
```

Note that `resize` event handler is set and also triggered so the action is fired on document ready.

Comment: I tried this with blank page to insure, but this is working only if I resize the window. Is this only for me happening? I tried with opera and firefox - last versions.

Comment: Its working here :  https://jsfiddle.net/fxo3skts/ check if you get an error in the chrome console

Comment: Yes, this is working there. Could you please translate it for JavaScript? This would help me very much

Comment: Ok, I figured this can't be corrected translated because of $ready.  Thank you. This is working as needed.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `dispatchEvent` to trigger the event. Also notice the event name is "resize". I am not using jQuery as your original post did not include any jQuery code.

```js
setTimeout(function () {
  window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
  }, 3000);

var called = 1;
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
   // if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 500) { //this demo is to show the resize is getting called
        document.getElementById('logger').innerHTML = 'resize called ' + called++;
   // }
}, false);
```

```html
<div id="logger"></div>
```

**Reference:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: Thank you for using JavaScript. I'm only learning it and this is much more simpler for me than JQuery. But this method have delay(correct me if I'm wrong, please) and I need it without any delay(like the normal script).

Comment: @beyevaza The delay (setTimeout) is just for **demo** purpose. Of course, you could just use the dispatchEvent anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

just wrap your code in a function, call it once during page initialization, and every time your event runs (`resize/resizing`)

```
function checkWidth( width ) {
  if ( document.documentElement.clientWidth < width ) {

    // my code

  }
}

checkWidth( 500 );

window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
  checkWidth( 500 );
}, false );
```

Essentially exactly what @nem commented :)

Comment: I think here the event is "resize" .. unless op is using something custom

Comment: i kept it the same as the `op`'s event, I find it strange all the other answers have converted his event and code to a different style, seeing as his problem was not with the event itself. :/

Comment: Thank you for noticing this, I typed it wrongly. I edit the post.

Comment: amended my answer to match ;)